# R: Optimization problem with equal coefficients

Tags: r, optimization, lpsolve

I would like to optimize a simple function such as:

```
max = a1 * x1 + a2 * x2 + a3 * x3
```

where the x's are known in advance and `a1 + a2 + a3 = limit`.
Furthermore, I need to add a constraint where `a1 = a2 = a3`. Would some know how this can be implemented using `lpSolveAPI`? This is what I already have:

```r
library(lpSolveAPI)
limit = 50
a <- c(1.5, 1.6, 2.5)
my.lp <- make.lp(0,3)
set.objfn(my.lp, a)
add.constraint(my.lp, 1:3, "=", limit)
lp.control(my.lp,sense='max')
my.lp
solve(my.lp)
```

Currently, I cannot seem to find a way to add the constraint `a1 = a2 = a3` (or `C1 = C2 = C3`).

Comment: The two constaints itself lead to single feasible solution `a1 = a2 = a3 = limit / 3`. You don't need to optimize anything then

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add constraint with two equals. You can split then into

```
a1 - a2 = 0
a1 - a3 = 0
```

That can be done using

```
add.constraint(my.lp, c(1, -1, 0), "=", 0)
add.constraint(my.lp, c(1, 0, -1), "=", 0)
```

But this optimization doesn't make sense to me as you have only one feasible solution so there is nothing to optimize.

**Edit:**
I've just noticed that your constraint isn't correct. What you have done is basically

```
x1 + 2 * x2 + 3 * x3 = limit
```

You need to change it to

```
add.constraint(my.lp, rep(1, 3), "=", limit)
```